# Stable matrices and their spectra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sp.spectral-theory

I am a graduate student in engineering and we work a lot with so-called Hurwitz (or stable) matrices.

A matrix in our terminology is called stable if the real part of the eigenvalues is strictly negative, [see for example here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_matrix#Hurwitz_stable_matrices).

Usually the problem for us is that such matrices are not normal, so the spectral theory of these matrices is quite complicated.

I am wondering however about the following property.

Let us assume we can show that there is an approximate eigenvalue, i.e. there is a almost eigenvector $u$ such that $\Vert (A-\lambda I)u \Vert<\varepsilon$ where $\Re (\lambda)=0$ and $\varepsilon>0.$

We engineers say then that $\lambda$ is in the $\varepsilon$ pseudospectrum of $A.$

I would like to know: Does this imply if $A$ is Hurwitz(or stable) that there exists an actual eigenvalue of $A$ in the half-plane $\left\{ \lambda \in \mathbb C: \Re(\lambda) \ge -\varepsilon \right\}$ or does this property above not tell me anything about the location of the spectrum?

I know that this would be true for normal matrices, but of course my matrix is not necessarily normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not true in general.

Note that in your condition you probably want to assume $\|u\|=1$ for otherwise you could always make the left hand side as small as you wish by making $u$ small. I will answer the question for the Euclidean norm and the induced spectral norm but this does not really make a huge difference.

Aassuming $\|u\|=1$, all that we learn from the condition is that $(A-\lambda I)u = y$ with $\|y\| < \varepsilon$. This can be rewritten to say
$$ (A - yu^T)u = \lambda  u$$
so that a perturbation of $A$ of size less than $\varepsilon$ moves one eigenvalue to the imaginary axis. Note that $\| yu^T\|=\|y\|$.

Now as you suspect, for nonnormal matrices perturbations of size $\varepsilon$ can have significant effects on the spectrum and there is no reason to assume that the effect is itself bounded by $\varepsilon$. To get more information you need to know more about $A$ and possibly about the type of perturbations that are of interest. There is a wealth of literature on this. As you are from engineering I suggest to read up on the concepts stability radii, spectral value sets and some of the introductory papers by Trefethen.

A small comment aside: you say that "we engineers say $\lambda$ is in the $\varepsilon$-pseudospectrum of $A$"; historically the term was first coined by mathematicians.